# Java using up far more memory than allocated with -Xmx

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, stack

I have a project I'm writing (in Java) for a class where the prof says we're not allowed to use more than 200m
I limit the stack memory to 50m (just to be absolutely sure) with -Xmx50m but according to top, it's still using 300m

I tried running [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and it reports only 26m

Could this all be memory on the stack?, I'm pretty sure I never go further than about 300 method calls deep (yes, it is a recursive DFS search), so that would have to mean every stack frame is using up almost a megabyte which seems hard to believe.

The program is single-threaded. Does anyone know any other places in which I might reduce memory usage?  Also, how can I check/limit how much memory the stack is using?

UPDATE: I'm using the following JVM options now with no effect (still about 300m according to top): `-Xss104k -Xms40m -Xmx40m -XX:MaxPermSize=1k`

Another UPDATE: Actually, if I let it run a little bit longer (with all these options) about half the time it suddenly drops to 150m after 4 or 5 seconds (the other half it doesn't drop).  What makes this really strange is that my program has no stochastic (and as I said it's single-threaded) so there's no reason it should behave differently on different runs

Could it have something to do with the JVM I'm using?

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~10.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

According to java -h, the default JVM is -server.  I tried adding -cacao and now (with all the other options) it's only 59m.  So I suppose this solves my problem.  Can anyone explain why this was necessary?  Also, are there any drawbacks I should know about?

One more update: cacao is really really slow compared to server.  This is an awful option

Comment: Heap memory and stack memory are configured separately. The memory you're seeing in top includes both.

Comment: I realize that, but I don't think it's stack memory.  I'm not using that much.  So where else could the memory be coming from

Comment: Are you setting the minimum heap size as well? If `-Xms` is larger than `-Xmx`, I think it uses up to `-Xms`

Comment: I'm using -server which I think sets a minimum heap size, but no not explicitly

Comment: Try setting it to 50m as well.

Comment: `-server` can only assign a minimum up to 64MB.

Comment: Not using -server doesn't change anything

Comment: Which column from `top` are you looking at? I think the one labeled `RES` will most closely reflect the amount of memory your program uses.

Comment: But this includes also the size of the shared libraries, etc. If you Prof allows 200m, then I'd interpret this as -Xmx200m, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: No, he specifically said "It can't use more than 200m total, and if you're using Java you'll have to figure out how to enforce that"

Answer (score 21):

Top command reflects the total amount of memory used by the Java application. This includes among other things:

- A basic memory overhead of the JVM itself
- the heap space (bounded with -Xmx)
- The permanent generation space (-XX:MaxPermSize - not standard in all JVMs)
- threads stack space (-Xss per stack) which may grow significantly depending on the number of threads
- Space used by native allocations (using ByteBufer class, or JNI)

Comment: No byte buffers (unless something in the collections framework uses them), limiting PermGen doesn't seem to change anything.  I do call System.arraycopy which I believe uses JNI, right?  Could that be it?

Comment: @dspyz: I don't think arrayCopy uses extra space outside of the heap space. It copies data from one heap location to another. I would re-check the number of threads spawned by your application.

Comment: No, single-threaded.  All I see (in eclipse debugger) is Main thread, Signal Dispatcher, Finalizer, and Reference Handler

Comment: @dspyz: What about shared memory of the process? I think you can check it with jmap (jmap <process id>). When you start multiple java processes, their total memory is not the sum as displayed by top, since they use shared libraries.

Comment: It also includes the size of shared libraries/dlls, and maybe the space the OS uses to cache loaded class files, etc.

Comment: Also, GC needs some memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854599/how-much-extra-memory-does-garbage-collection-require

Answer (score 11):

```
Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss]
```

here max heap memory as   -Xmx ,min heap memory as -Xms,stack memory as  -Xss
and  -XX maxPermSize

The following example illustrates this situation. I have launched my tomcat with the following startup parameters:

```
-Xmx168m -Xms168m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=32m -Xss1m
```

Answer (score 6):

With `-Xmx` you are configuring heap size. To configure stack size use `-Xss` parameter. Sum of those two parameters should be approximately what you want:

```
-Xmx150m -Xss50m
```

for example.

Additionally there is also `-XX:MaxPermSize` parameter which controls. This parameter for `-client` has default value of 32mb and for `-server` 64mb. According to your configuration calculate it as well. PermGen space is:

> The permanent generation is used to hold reflective of the VM itself such as class objects and method objects.

So basically it stores internal data of the JVM, like classes definitions and intern-ed strings.

At the end I must say that there is one part which you can't control, that is memory used by native java process. Java is program, just like any other, so it uses memory also. If you are watching memory usage in Task Manager you will see this memory as well together with your program memory consumption.

Comment: Don't forget PermGen space

Comment: Thank you, I just found and tried that.  It made no difference.  I'm not using up stack memory.  Where else could it be coming from if it's not heap or stack

Comment: What's PermGen space and how do I limit it?

Comment: Loaded classes go there and I think maybe some statics. You can set it with -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

Comment: Yes, but I've run java programs which easily use less than 300m before.  The memory used by the native java process is just constant overhead, isn't it?

Comment: Not constant. That is process which is live. It changes during time. Also there is a lot of difference between different versions. I can see that memory used be Java in 1.6 more than by 1.5.

Comment: When I say "before", I mean a couple weeks ago.  Our prof puts the same 200m restriction on all our projects.  I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: Permgen will die forget it

Comment: Note that -Xss sets **single thread stack size**. The total stack memory usage will be _-Xss * number of threads_.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to note that "total memory used" (RSS in Linux land) includes JDK heap (+ other JDK areas) as well as any "native memory" allocated.

For instance, these people found that allocating too many jaxbcontexts (which have associated native memory) between GC's could cause it to use a lot of extra RAM.  Another common one is apparently ZipInflater if you don't call close on it (or GZipStream, etc.)

http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2014/08/jvm-native-memory-leak.html

His final workaround/fix was to either GC "more often" (by using GC1 garbage collector, or specifying a *smaller* [ironically] -Xmx setting) or by cacheing the JaxBContext objects (since they have no close method so you can't control the leak).

Also note that sometimes you can find memory culprits by just examing jstack: http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/09/jaxbcontext-performance-problem-case.html

It's also sometimes possible to "miss" closing for instance GZipStreams accidentally http://kohsuke.org/2011/11/03/quiz-time-memory-leak-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using JVisualVM?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

I've often found it helps me track this stuff down. It will show you how much of each kind of memory is being used in even let you drill in and find out what.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a version available for linux

Comment: It should be in the bin directory of the JDK (not the JRE); which may not be on your PATH.