# How To Append the Large Text Files to JTextArea in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have implemented an Java Swing Application.In that I have wrote Open File Functionality.I have tried with lot of ways to read the file and write into the JTextArea(I have tried with append(),setText() and read() method also).But,It working upto 100 MB.If I want to open over 100 MB file It raises an "out of Memory Exception : Java Heap space" at textarea.append().Is there any way to append over 100MB data to JTextArea or Anyway to Increase the Memory capacity of JTextArea.Please give a Suggestions for the above issue.Thanking You.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [Java using up far more memory than allocated with -Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282178/java-using-up-far-more-memory-than-allocated-with-xmx) as your problem is really that your java-instance is running out of memory.
Java can open (theoretically) files of any size, as long as you have the memory for it to be read.

I would however recommend that you only read in parts of a file in memory at a time. And when you've finish with that part you move on to the next specified amount of text.

Anyhow, for this instance and if this is not a regular problem, you could use `-Xmx800m` which would let java use 800mb for heap space.

If this is **not** a one time thing, you *really* should look in to just reading in parts of a file at a time. http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file should put you in the right direction.

Comment: I have Developed my Project by using Netbeans IDE.I had set VM option upto -Xmx1024m.But, issue is not resolved.I got same Exception.