# Why is this the case gc

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

my jdk version is "1.8.0_40"
my code is   .

```
public class Test {  

    private static int _1M = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        byte[] b, b1, b2, b3;
        b = new byte[2 * _1M];
        b1 = new byte[2 * _1M];
        b2 = new byte[2 * _1M];
        b3 = new byte[4 * _1M];

    }
}
```

my runtime argument is

```
-verbose:gc -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
```

I run my code, i got this gc result,

```
Heap
PSYoungGen      total 9216K, used 7987K [0x00000007bf600000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
eden space 8192K, 97% used [0x00000007bf600000,0x00000007bfdccd60,0x00000007bfe00000)
from space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bff00000,0x00000007bff00000,0x00000007c0000000)
to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bff00000)
ParOldGen       total 10240K, used 4096K [0x00000007bec00000, 0x00000007bf600000, 0x00000007bf600000)
object space 10240K, 40% used [0x00000007bec00000,0x00000007bf000010,0x00000007bf600000)
Metaspace       used 3084K, capacity 4494K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
class space    used 339K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

you can see gc result,the total memory is 12M,but my code is only 10M.and this code don't run gc . 
Why is this？

Comment: "Why is this" is pretty vogue... can you be more specific with your question ?

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in several places, e.g.: [Java using up far more memory than allocated with -Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282178/java-using-up-far-more-memory-than-allocated-with-xmx) or https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx

Long story short: your program is using 10M of heap, but heap is only part of the memory consumed by the JVM.  There are internal data structures used by the GC algorithms, JIT compilers, etc., those can take even double the total memory usage of your JVM.

Comment: thanks,but why does internal data structures used 2M memory.Could they use a fixed size?

Comment: The additional memory will be roughly proportional to the size of your heap (e.g.: GC needs to keep track of more objects).  Your additional usage (+20%) seems a bit high, but nothing out of the ordinary in my experience.

AFAIK there is no way to examine the exact contents of JVM internal datastructures (e.g. you can't tell how much is used by GC-related datastructure, and what these are), other than inspecting the process' memory.